# Windows Boot disc to save files?

Tags: windows, backup, external-hard-drive, crash, livecd

Somehow after updating my legit windows 7 OS with no pirated or mod software on my PC i was welcome to a black screen. I popped in my ghost disc and copied the files i need to an external HD. IIRC windows 7 disc can do that too. Problem with the way i did it on ghost was it excepted me to select 1 file (an HD disc image) so i couldnt select multiple folders to move. Also when i did move i had no idea if it finished or how long it would take.

My linux live cd couldnt access the HD. Anyways, is there a disc i can use to easily copy files from my laptop to my external HD? I think ghost, windows 7 and windows server all allow me but is there one that is better suited to copy files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WinPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment) and just do XCOPY or ROBOCOPY